# How do I use label in this part of this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting the same error when using label this way in this query. I keep getting a syntax error.

```
SELECT idint, elVal.idinterventovalore, concat(cast(elVal.idinterventovalore as varchar(5)) , '=' , valore as label, 1 like value) -- , elVal.IDInterventoRagg
FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi_valori val 
    INNER JOIN cch.pats_cch_interventielencovalori elVal ON val.idinterventoragg = elVal.idinterventoragg AND val.idinterventovalore = elVal.idinterventovalore 
WHERE elVal.idinterventoragg like '%DiaValvulopatiaSede%' AND elVal.IDTipo='I'
ORDER BY idint, elVal.idinterventovalore;
```

--and this below is the source code that I am debugging--

```sql
SELECT IDInt, 
       elVal.IDInterventoValore, 
       cast(elVal.IDInterventoValore as varchar(5)) + '=' + Valore as label, 
       1 as [value] -- , elVal.IDInterventoRagg 
FROM AppManager_BI.PATS_CCH_Interventi_Valori val 
  INNER JOIN AppManager_BI.PATS_CCH_InterventiElencoValori elVal 
          ON val.IDInterventoRagg = elVal.IDInterventoRagg 
         AND val.IDInterventoValore = elVal.IDInterventoValore 
WHERE elVal.IDInterventoRagg like 'DiaVasculopatiaPerifericaSede' 
  AND elVal.IDTipo='I' 
ORDER BY IDInt, elVal.IDInterventoValore
```

Comment: sorry that 1 like value is supposed to be 1 as value

Comment: also the error that I get is a syntax error in ''as'' label

Comment: ok @a_horse_with_no_name but what if I want to use valore as label?

Comment: So basically I am trying to understand what the programmers did before and I am debugging the errors, while renaming the fields by the new field names that are used in the new database . But this first line seems unclear to me. If you want to take a look I am going to comment down here the query that they first wrote without any changes that I made yet.

Comment: SELECT IDInt, elVal.IDInterventoValore, cast(elVal.IDInterventoValore as varchar(5)) + '=' + Valore as label, 1 as [value]  -- , elVal.IDInterventoRagg
FROM AppManager_BI.PATS_CCH_Interventi_Valori val 
 INNER JOIN AppManager_BI.PATS_CCH_InterventiElencoValori elVal ON val.IDInterventoRagg = elVal.IDInterventoRagg AND val.IDInterventoValore = elVal.IDInterventoValore 
WHERE elVal.IDInterventoRagg like 'DiaVasculopatiaPerifericaSede' AND elVal.IDTipo='I'
ORDER BY IDInt, elVal.IDInterventoValore

Comment: it is in the edited version o fthe question now

Comment: My problem is that I cannot run the old query because the references to the old database do not exist anymore and I don't understand how they wanted the output simply by reading the old query

Comment: because I mean... I could simply label everything in the concat but I am really not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the original query (presumably T-SQL), you probably want:

```
SELECT IDInt, elVal.IDInterventoValore, 
       concat(elVal.IDInterventoValore, '=', Valore) as label, 
       1 as value,
...
```

there is no need to cast the value when using `concat()`

If you want to properly deal with possible empty values in the two colums, `concat_ws()` might be a better choice:

```
SELECT IDInt, elVal.IDInterventoValore, 
       concat_ws('=', elVal.IDInterventoValore, Valore) as label, 
       1 as value,
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a newbee in this world! This was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't work on postgresql, but I understand that your use of alias inside `concat` is invalid.
Try below code.

```
SELECT idint, 
           elVal.idinterventovalore, 
           concat(cast(elVal.idinterventovalore as varchar(5)) , '=' , valore, 1) -- , elVal.IDInterventoRagg
      FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi_valori val 
INNER JOIN cch.pats_cch_interventielencovalori elVal 
        ON val.idinterventoragg = elVal.idinterventoragg 
       AND val.idinterventovalore = elVal.idinterventovalore 
     WHERE elVal.idinterventoragg like '%DiaValvulopatiaSede%'
       AND elVal.IDTipo='I'
  ORDER BY idint,
           elVal.idinterventovalore;
```

Hope this will help you.